# In-place Cholesky inverse

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix, cuda

I would like to know if it's possible to get the inverse of matrix by Cholesky factorization without the need of temporary arrays. As of now I can get the cholesky factorization without the use of temporary arrays, but from there I haven't figured out a way for obtaining the inverse of the original matrix without recurring to a temporary matrix of the same dimension as the original. That is, solving the system

```
A x_i = e_i, where e_i is the i-th column if the identity matrix.
```

I'm actually following a slightly better way as described in http://arxiv.org/abs/1111.4144

### Some context:

I'm writing a (C/C++) CUDA program in which each thread computes the inverse and determinant of a relatively small (20x20, and in some cases 40x40) covariance matrix, among other tasks. Using arrays in CUDA is not very fast, that's why I would like to minimize their use. I've already seen some major improvement when I coded the in-place cholesky factorization and restricting the use of only the lower entries of the matrices, that's why I expect some improvement if I manage to get rid of the temporary array in the equation solving part, i.e. it would be ok if the algorithm uses temporary variables as at the very least smaller arrays.

I'm aware that computing `x = A^{-1} b,` which is exactly what I do in the end, is more efficient by solving the system `A x = b` than computing the inverse. But as I require the determinant as well, obtained in the Cholesky factorization, I thought it would be better to compute the inverse.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if what I am going to say would help you or not. But accessing arrays in CUDA can cost 16x and it can cost only 1x. it depends on the memory arrangement and the access pattern each thread would do.

for me lets say I have 100 thread and each thread needs a matrix of size 20x20 integers/floats. If I were you would not hestiate to use only one array that is shared among all the threads  and each thread would access the first element like this:

```
int iFirstElement = gArray[tid]; // where tid is the thread idx assuming this 1D,2D, or 3D I am sure you can calculate the tid easily.
//to access the second element you can use this:
int iSecondElement = gArray[numOfThreads * 1 + tid];
// to access the third element you can use this
int iSecondElement = gArray[numOfThreads * 2 + tid];
```

this way you will enhance the memory access pattern and only consume 1X to access the memory instead of 16x. You may think global memory is a bad idea but trust me it is not. you can go back to my published paper that do face detection on the GPU to read more about memory access patterns.

http://ijces.org/media/1Iss8-IJCES0402603_v4_iss2_47-55.pdf

Finally extensive use of local variables would cause the scheduler to run the block in multiple cycles as the register file per block won't be enough to run the whole block at the same time.

Comment: Well that could be a way to go forward, however it would be really really hard to change the parallelization scheme I have now.

Comment: It may seems hard and difficult to debug. but on of colleagues doing PhD with DNA and Proteins on CUDA did not believe that would pay off till we changed it and the time needed for the algorithm got reduced  from 36 seconds to 0.54 seconds

Comment: Please read the GPU architecture section of the paper I am referring to, to better understand the trade off between the different memory types.

Comment: I took a longer read through your paper. I'm already making coalesced memory access where I can. My question was more on the sense of changing the algorithm some how to decrease use and access of memory.

Comment: Actually you did not make coalesced pattern in your code at all. Reduce the number of memory access is not the goal the real goal is reduce uncoalesced pattern or move frequently accessed data to local variable(s). On the other hand extensive use of local variables would cause the scheduler to execute the warp in multiple cycles as the register file size is limited. I am happy to discuss this on Skype 'mahmoudfayezahmed'